# remove click delay on mobile browsers

Tags: angular, click

How to remove famous 300ms delay on mobile browsers in an angular(2+) app?

I have used [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) with jQuery, but what about angular?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check yet, but it seems putting this in the `<head>` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

and this in your stylesheet would do the trick:

```
html {
  touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

Found here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away

Answer (score 0):

there is npm module for make this, is the same behaviur of jquery fastclick

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-fastclick

Comment: it's for angularJS, isn't it?

Comment: according to issue#1, it's only for AngularJS (1.x)
: https://github.com/streamsure/angular-fastclick/issues/1